# Generating PublicKey from x and y values of elliptic curve point

Tags: android, bouncycastle, spongycastle

I am trying to generate a shared secret in my app like this:

```
public static byte[] generateSharedSecret(PrivateKey privateKey PublicKey publicKey) {
    KeyAgreement keyAgreement = KeyAgreement.getInstance("ECDH", "SC");
    keyAgreement.init(privateKey);
    keyAgreement.doPhase(publicKey, true);
    return keyAgreement.generateSecret();
}
```

This is working fine, but the `PublicKey` I use here should be coming from the backend.

The backend just sends me the `x` and `y` value of a point on an elliptic curve and now I am supposed to generate the `PublicKey` from that. But I just can't figure it out! How can I create a `PublicKey` instance just from those two values?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's actually quite simple! But you need one more thing besides the `x` and `y` values. You also need an `ECParameterSpec`! The `ECParameterSpec` describes the elliptic curve you are using and your app has to use the same `ECParameterSpec` as your backend does!

---

With the `x` and `y` values you can create an `ECPoint` instance and together with your `ECParameterSpec` you can create an `ECPublicKeySpec`:

```
ECParameterSpec ecParameters = ...;
BigInteger x = ...;
BigInteger y = ...;

ECPoint ecPoint = new ECPoint(x, y);
ECPublicKeySpec keySpec = new ECPublicKeySpec(ecPoint, ecParameters);
```

And now with that `ECPublicKeySpec` you can generate the `PublicKey` using a `KeyFactory`:

```
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
```

---

You can find more information about this topic [**here**](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Elliptic+Curve+Key+Pair+Generation+and+Key+Factories).