# How to generate ECPublic Key from given X component, Y component and curve in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, openssl, commoncrypto, ecdhe

I am getting X component, Y component and curve values from server. I want to derive server public key from that using openssl or common crypto.

In iOS there is no straight forward API to generate Public Key with a given X,Y & Curve values.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you are asking solution similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116758/Generating%20PublicKey%20from%20x%20and%20y%20values%20of%20elliptic%20curve%20point/30184609. Though I am not having exact implementation logic... will share once I found it.